# Large SpMat object with RcppArmadillo

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, rcpp, armadillo

I am trying to learn and use Rcpp and RcppArmadillo for the sparse linear algebra routines.

Code below is adaptation of the example here: http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/armadillo-sparse-matrix/

```
code <- '
  S4 matx(x);
  IntegerVector Xd = matx.slot("Dim");
  IntegerVector Xi = matx.slot("i");
  IntegerVector Xp = matx.slot("p");
  NumericVector Xx = matx.slot("x");

  arma::sp_mat Xsp(Xd[0], Xd[1]);

  // create space for values, and copy
  arma::access::rw(Xsp.values) = arma::memory::acquire_chunked<double>(Xx.size() + 1);
  arma::arrayops::copy(arma::access::rwp(Xsp.values), 
             Xx.begin(), 
             Xx.size() + 1);

  // create space for row_indices, and copy -- so far in a lame loop
  arma::access::rw(Xsp.row_indices) = arma::memory::acquire_chunked<arma::uword>(Xx.size() + 1);
  for (int j=0; j<Xi.size(); j++)
    arma::access::rwp(Xsp.row_indices)[j] = Xi[j];

  // create space for col_ptrs, and copy -- so far in a lame loop
  arma::access::rw(Xsp.col_ptrs) = arma::memory::acquire_chunked<arma::uword>(Xp.size() + 1);
  for (int j=0; j<Xp.size(); j++)
      arma::access::rwp(Xsp.col_ptrs)[j] = Xp[j];

  // important: set the sentinel as well
  arma::access::rwp(Xsp.col_ptrs)[Xp.size()+1] = std::numeric_limits<arma::uword>::max();

  // set the number of non-zero elements
  arma::access::rw(Xsp.n_nonzero) = Xx.size();

  Rcout << "SpMat Xsp:\\n" << arma::dot(Xsp,Xsp) << std::endl;
'

norm2 <- cxxfunction(signature(x="Matrix"),
                     code,plugin="RcppArmadillo")
```

When I use a vector of 1e4, things work fine:

```
> p <- 10000
> X <- Matrix(rnorm(p),sparse=TRUE)
> norm2(X)
SpMat Xsp:
9997.14
NULL
```

However, when I use a vector of length 1e5, an error is produced

```
> p <- 100000
> X <- Matrix(rnorm(p),sparse=TRUE)
> norm2(X)

error: SpMat::init(): requested size is too large

Error: 
>
```

I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.
Any pointers would be appreciated.

============== more information ==============

The problem seems to be with having dimension >= 2^16=65536

Following works:

```
> m <- 1000
> n <- 65535
> nnz <- 10000
> iind <- sample.int(m,nnz,replace=TRUE)
> jind <- sample.int(n,nnz,replace=TRUE)
> xval <- rnorm(nnz)
> X <- sparseMatrix(i=iind,j=jind,x=xval,dims=c(m,n))
> norm2(X)
SpMat Xsp:
10029.8
NULL
```

Following doesn't work:

```
> m <- 1000
> n <- 65536
> nnz <- 10000
> iind <- sample.int(m,nnz,replace=TRUE)
> jind <- sample.int(n,nnz,replace=TRUE)
> xval <- rnorm(nnz)
> X <- sparseMatrix(i=iind,j=jind,x=xval,dims=c(m,n))
> norm2(X)

error: SpMat::init(): requested size is too large

Error: 
>
```

Why would this be the case?

Comment: This was an Armadillo bug.  I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrix seems odd.  By saying

```
 Matrix(rnorm(p),sparse=TRUE)
```

you end up with a p x 1 matrix, albeit sparse.  If I just assign 10 rows or colums things
just work.

```
R> p <- 100000
R> X <- Matrix(rnorm(p),nrow=10,sparse=TRUE)
R> dim(X)
[1]    10 10000
R> norm2(X)
SpMat Xsp:
100832
NULL
R>
```

So I think you just need a better sparse matrix to work with -- the conversion code, and Armadillo's sparse Matrix type, are fine.

**Update on 2013-04-30**:  This was actually an Armadillo bug, which was just fixed upstream.  A new RcppArmadillo verion 0.3.810.2 is now in SVN, and should migrate soon to CRAN shortly.  You no longer need to define `ARMA_64BIT_WORD`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was just testing to see if things worked, so I didn't bother making a "sparse" matrix. Also, px1 matrix is still a matrix. I was wondering if there was a limit on the number of non-zero elements. With additional testing, I was able to find that the dimension of the matrix is limited to 2^16-1=65535. This is not very large, especially if the matrix is sparse. I hope there is something I can do to form a larger matrix.

Comment: Is it possible to specify "includes" to go above the "#include <RcppArmadillo.h>" with cxxfunction? This would be very handy and does not require modifying the RcppArmadillo package installation. Thanks!

Comment: `cxxfunction()` is a simple helper. It sounds like you want to have more control, so you should *really* consider creating a package.

Comment: BTW you can also create a `#define foo` by adding a `-Dfoo` compiler option.  That will work with `cxxfunction` too.

Comment: Feel free to accept and/or upvote the answer for the comment then :)  BTW which (Rcpp)Armadillo version are you using?

Comment: I am using Rcpp version 0.10.3 and RcppArmadillo version 0.3.810.0. R version 3.0.0 compiled with MKL libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the update. (And no, you don't "compile with MKL". One uses MKL as one of several possible libraries providing BLAS.)

Comment: I wonder if we can use this in a package. After trying to compile the package with and without PKG_CXXFLAGS=-DARMA_64BIT_WORD  I'm still not able to create sparse matrices bigger than 65,535 x 65,535. I've realized that the RcppArmadilloConfig.h (version 0.6.600.4.0)  file has ARMA_32BIT_WORD 1 so it actually prevents using ARMA_64BIT_WORD (I think?). Any way I can solve this, or I just have to deal with R (3.2.4 Revised (2016-03-16 r70336)) not been able to handle 64INT? Thanks!

Comment: Try _locally_ setting `ARMA_64BIT_WORD` (check how) -- I can't at the package level as it breaks existing code.  It will likely help you.  If you set it before the `#include <RcppArmadillo.h>` things may just work.  That at least is the pln. (And you should have asked on rcpp-devel to get more than two eyeballs on this...)  And yes the other answer basically says the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this: http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#config_hpp.

The solution is to set the 64 bit integer option by adding a line above the header file for armadillo:

```
#define ARMA_64BIT_WORD
```

I put this in [R root]/lib/R/library/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadilloConfig.h

I had tried using "includes" parameter for cxxfunction, but I think this define statement has to be above the include statement,

```
#include RcppArmadillo.h
```

in the cpp code. I don't know if cxxfunction of the inline package allows this.

After modifying the RcppArmadilloConfig.h, I can now declare a matrix larger than 2^16.

```
> m <- 1000
> n <- 65536+1000
> nnz <- 10000
> iind <- sample.int(m,nnz,replace=TRUE)
> jind <- sample.int(n,nnz,replace=TRUE)
> xval <- rnorm(nnz)
> X <- sparseMatrix(i=iind,j=jind,x=xval,dims=c(m,n))
> norm2(X)
SpMat Xsp:
10218.8
NULL
>
```

Comment: You can also define compiler switches on the fly via `-D`: `g++ -DARMA_64BIT_WORD` and/or add the define to your package's `src/Makevars` or `src/Makevars.win}`.