# Large Matrices in RcppArmadillo via the ARMA_64BIT_WORD define

Tags: r, rcpp

From a previous post, [Large SpMat object with RcppArmadillo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16159174/large-spmat-object-with-rcpparmadillo), I decided to use `Rcpp` to compute a large matrix (~600,000 rows x 11 cols)

I've installed `Rcpp` and `RcppArmadillo`

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] RcppArmadillo_0.7.500.0.0 Rcpp_0.12.7               cluster_2.0.4             skmeans_0.2-8            
 [5] ggdendro_0.1-20           ggplot2_2.1.0             lsa_0.73.1                SnowballC_0.5.1          
 [9] data.table_1.9.6          jsonlite_1.1              purrr_0.2.2               stringi_1.1.2            
[13] dplyr_0.5.0               plyr_1.8.4 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] assertthat_0.1   slam_0.1-38      MASS_7.3-45      chron_2.3-47     grid_3.3.1       R6_2.2.0         gtable_0.2.0    
 [8] DBI_0.5-1        magrittr_1.5     scales_0.4.0     tools_3.3.1      munsell_0.4.3    clue_0.3-51      colorspace_1.2-7
[15] tibble_1.2
```

With an example such as `mtcars` this works perfect:

```
library(lsa)    
x <- as.matrix(mtcars)
cosine(t(x))
```

This is `cosine` function from `lsa`:

```
cosR <- function(x) {
      co <- array(0, c(ncol(x), ncol(x)))
      ## f <- colnames(x)
      ## dimnames(co) <- list(f, f)
      for (i in 2:ncol(x)) {
        for (j in 1:(i - 1)) {
            co[i,j] <- crossprod(x[,i], x[,j])/
                sqrt(crossprod(x[,i]) * crossprod(x[,j]))
        }
    }
    co <- co + t(co)
    diag(co) <- 1
    return(as.matrix(co))
}
```

And the equivalent in `Rcpp` is this:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(RcppArmadillo)
cppFunction(depends='RcppArmadillo',
            code="NumericMatrix cosCpp(NumericMatrix Xr) {
            int n = Xr.nrow(), k = Xr.ncol();
            arma::mat X(Xr.begin(), n, k, false); // reuses memory and avoids extra copy
            arma::mat Y = arma::trans(X) * X; // matrix product
            arma::mat res = Y / (arma::sqrt(arma::diagvec(Y)) * arma::trans(arma::sqrt(arma::diagvec(Y))));
            return Rcpp::wrap(res);
           }")
```

You can check the two functions are equivalent

```
all.equal(cosCpp(x),cosR(x))
[1] TRUE
```

But when I run this with my data after loading `Rcpp` I obtain:

```
x <- as.matrix(my_data)
x <- t(my_data)
y <- cosCpp(x)
error: Mat::init(): requested size is too large
Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
  Mat::init(): requested size is too large
```

**Update** *Solution after @Coatless's suggestion + [@gvegayon](https://github.com/gvegayon/arma64bit) post + hours of reading*

I modified my function to this:

```
sourceCpp("/myfolder/my_function.cpp")
```

and the content of `my_function.cpp` is

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::sp_mat cosine_rcpp(
    const arma::mat & X
) {

  int k = X.n_cols;

  arma::sp_mat ans(k,k);

  for (int i=0;i<k;i++)
    for (int j=i;j<k;j++) {
      // X(i) x X(j)' / sqrt(sum(X^2) * sum(Y^2))
      ans.at(i,j) = arma::norm_dot(X.col(i), X.col(j));

    }

    return ans;
}
```

Then I run

```
cosine_rcpp(x)
```

Comment: For future reference, *"[...] says I should enable `ARMA_64BIT_WORD` but I had no luck enabling it"* is not helpful; state (and possibly demonstrate) what you tried in your question.

Comment: Please do yourself (and us) a favour and use `sourceCpp()`.  Anything beyond two or three lines gets out of hand with `cppFunction()`.

Comment: Hi. sourceCpp() was cool !! I just posted an attempt of solution. I never *ever* worked with C++ before

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. `RcppArmadillo` is an `Rcpp`-only package due to the contents in the `/src` directory. To enable C++11 use `// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]`
2. `ARMA_64BIT_WORD` is not defined. To define it add `#define ARMA_64BIT_WORD 1` prior to the `#include <RcppArmadillo.h>`.

Sample implementation using `sourceCpp()`

```
#define ARMA_64BIT_WORD 1
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]] 

// [[Rcpp::export]] 
arma::mat cosCpp(const arma::mat& X) {

    arma::mat Y = arma::trans(X) * X; // matrix product
    arma::mat res = Y / (arma::sqrt(arma::diagvec(Y)) * arma::trans(arma::sqrt(arma::diagvec(Y))));

    return res;
}
```

To define it within the `/src/Makevars{.win}` for a package use:

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS = -DARMA_64BIT_WORD=1
```

Comment: @pachamaltese : Source the above code use `sourceCpp(code =" ")` or place it in an external file `test.cpp` and source it via `sourceCpp(file="/path/to/test.cpp")`

Comment: thanks @Coatless . Including `cpp11` creates another error that I'm posting in an update now.

Comment: Comment largely for myself when I inevitably come back to this: order matters! Can't just add the `#define` statement anywhere, the being before the `#include` really does matter *headdesk*

Comment: @alexpghayes the reason it matters is that when you #include, you insert the RcppArmadillo code there. It checks “is ARMA_64BIT_WORD defined?”. So you need to define it before it checks