# Handling extremely large and sparse matrices in RcppArmadillo

Tags: r, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I'm trying to pass a diagonal matrix `W` to an Rcpp function. The problem is that `W` has size 1,000,000 by 1,000,000, which is (I think) well outside the limits Armadillo allows (even when using a C++11 compiler with ARMA_64BIT_WORD enabled).

Since `W` is a diagonal matrix, it is extremely sparse. For that reason, I first generated a dense representation of `W` (using the Matrix package function Diagonal). I then passed these compressed representation of `W` to my function. I thought this would solve any memory problems. Here's a small example:

**C++ Code:**

```
#define ARMA_64BIT_WORD 1
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
int test(sp_mat W){
  
  return 0;
  
}
```

**R Code:**

```
# define the diagonal matrix
nrows <- 1e6
W <- Matrix::Diagonal(nrows)

# call Rcpp function
test(W)
```

However, despite using a compressed representation, I still get this error.

```
error: SpMat::init(): requested size is too large; suggest to compile in C++11 mode and/or enable ARMA_64BIT_WORD
```

Is there any way to handle `W` so that I can pass it into `test` and perform matrix operations?

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40592054/large-matrices-in-rcpparmadillo-via-the-arma-64bit-word-define). However, I think the solution provided by @Dirk worked in that case since the input matrix was still small compared to my `W`.

Comment: _If_ the matrix has sufficient sparsity _and_ you use the right tools you can do this.  You need to experiment.  What $N$ works is also a function ... of your machine and its RAM allotment.  There are different ways to construct sparse matrices.  We have some converters  from R thanks the Google Summer of Code project a few years ago; you can also try directly in C++ using Armadillo functions to triangulate the issue.

Comment: BTW your example works on my machine just fine--even for 1e7 and 1e8. Maybe I have more RAM than you---though it is not "that much".

Comment: Interesting, thanks for testing it. I have 16GB of RAM on my machine. Is there any way I can tell if a C++11 compiler is *definitely* being used and ARMA_64BIT_WORD is enabled? I removed the comments from the config.hpp file, and I still get the above error.

Comment: Maybe I should move that to an answer instead of a comment...  Do `sourceCpp(filename, verbose=TRUE)` and you should see the C++ standard invoked---R 4.0.* itself makes it C++11 these days.  What does `g++ --version` say for you?

Comment: It says `g++  -std=gnu++11`. It also has `C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/g++` listed in the output. Could this mean I'm not using the 64 bit version? There's also this call to `dyn.load`: `.sourceCpp_1_DLLInfo <- dyn.load('C:/Users/ralph/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpaKLEIw/sourceCpp-i386-w64-mingw32-1.0.5/sourcecpp_9bc23c31b/sourceCpp_9.dll')`

Comment: With RTool 4.0 you should be fine, and also be using the 64-bit version by defaiult.  What I can't remember is whether Windos gets in your way or not.   But in any event... no Rcpp or RcppArmadillo issue here AFAICT.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I added `CXX_STD =-CX11` and `PKG_CXXFLAGS=-ARMA_64BIT_WORD` as environment variables. Now I get the error: `g++.exe: error: ARMA_64BIT_WORD: No such file or directory`

Comment: You need a `D` for `define` there: `-DARMA_64BIT_WORD`. And no minus before `CX11` instead   `CXX_STD = CXX11`.

Comment: Strange. I can see -DARMA_64BIT_WORD in the cmd line call, but still the same error. `C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -fopenmp  -I"C:/Users/ralph/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/ralph/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"C:/Users/ralph/Desktop/asp"     -DARMA_64BIT_WORD   -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c maincpp.cpp -o maincpp.o`

I will keep at it.

Comment: (If it is in your source file as originally then you don't have the problem as you don't need to set it again. Ditto with C++11 which is already the default.)

Comment: I changed to a different windows machine and it ran fine, even for 1e7 and 1e8. I might try a fresh installation of R and Rtools on the original machine and try again. Thanks for the assistance @Dirk.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out.  Let me put closure on it by posted my (slightlty edited / simplified) version of your code.  Feel to accept it, it shows another trick or two.  But by and large you had this right already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The originally posted code was actually correct, but somehow the machine it was running on was not---see the discussion above for details.

As an add-on, here is a slightly edited version of the code without global namespace, actual access to the matrix (passing was enough, this is simply more explicit) and returning `void`.  We also added the usual 'call it from R for me' trick one can do with Rcpp Attributes.

#### Code

```
// lightly edited version of question, working fine for me
#define ARMA_64BIT_WORD 1
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void spmatTest(arma::sp_mat M) {
  // show a simple access of matrix,
  // here we just sum elements on diagonal
  Rcpp::Rcout << "Sum of diag is "
              << arma::as_scalar(arma::sum(M.diag()))
              << std::endl;
}

/*** R
spmatTest( Matrix::Diagonal( 1e6 ))
spmatTest( Matrix::Diagonal( 1e7 ))
spmatTest( Matrix::Diagonal( 1e8 ))
*/
```

#### Output

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/64428776/answer.cpp")

R> spmatTest( Matrix::Diagonal( 1e6 ))
Sum of diag is 1e+06

R> spmatTest( Matrix::Diagonal( 1e7 ))
Sum of diag is 1e+07

R> spmatTest( Matrix::Diagonal( 1e8 ))
Sum of diag is 1e+08
R>
```